# Django 1.6: Order objects by boolean and likes

Tags: python, django, sorting

I have a doctors model where I'm displaying doctor objects based on highest likes. I have a boolean field for every doctor if that doctor is sponsored or not. I want to show the sponsored doctors first and then rest of them should be sorted based on highest likes.

here is what I've to sort by netlikes and it's working

```
doctors = Doctor.objects.all().order_by('-netlikes')
```

I tried this but didn't make any difference

```
doctors = Doctor.objects.all().order_by('sponsored').order_by('-netlikes')
```

doctors model.py

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1300, null = True, blank = True)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)
    education1 = models.CharField(max_length=1300)
    gender_choices = ( ('Male', 'Male'), ('Female','Female'),)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices = gender_choices, null=True, blank = True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/', null=True, blank = True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    netlikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null = True, blank = True)
    sponsored = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

Any idea on how can I show the sponsored doctors first and then highest liked ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't chain `order_by` in django, the last one overrides all previous ordering. To avoid it, just use

```
doctors = Doctor.objects.all().order_by('sponsored', '-netlikes')
```